# Magento 2 : How to get product attributes in my module block function which are visible on frontend?

Tags: attributes, magento2.2.2, eav-attributes, visibility

Issue is I am getting all the attribute collection not the attributes which are visible on frontend I am unable to filter them as the data which is coming is from Table: eav_attribute from there we can't filter it as in that table there is no column for "is_visible_on_frontend" Actually data I need is existing in Table: catalog_eav_attribute there is column for visibility.
Please check my code which I am using in my custom module block file.

**Main Function for calling attribute is getallattributes() & Model is  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory**

```
class ProductList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

protected $scopeConfig;
protected $_attributeFactory;
protected $displayattributes;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
         \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory,
          \Ghrix\PrintCatalog\Model\Config\Source\Displayattributes $displayattributes
         ){
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    $this->displayattributes = $displayattributes;
}

public function getcategoryId()
{
    if (!$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('modulesettings/catalogprint/settings', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {
     return ;
    }
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
    $catid = $category->getId();

    return $catid; 

}
public function getcategoryname()
{
    if (!$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('modulesettings/catalogprint/settings', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {
     return ;
    }
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
    $catname = $category->getName();
    return $catname; 

}
public function productswithprices()
{
    if (!$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('modulesettings/catalogprint/settings', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {
     return ;
    }
    $myvalue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('modulesettings/catalogprint/productswithprices', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    return $myvalue;
}
public function productswithrrp()
{
    if (!$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('modulesettings/catalogprint/settings', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {
     return ;
    }
    $myvalue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('modulesettings/catalogprint/productswithrrp', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    return $myvalue;
}
public function productswithsku()
{
    if (!$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('modulesettings/catalogprint/settings', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {
     return ;
    }
    $myvalue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('modulesettings/catalogprint/productswithsku', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    return $myvalue;
}

public function displaymode()
{
    if (!$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('modulesettings/catalogprint/settings', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {
     return ;
    }
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
    $mode  = $category->getDisplayMode();
    return $mode;
}
public function selectedattributes()
{
    if (!$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('modulesettings/catalogprint/settings', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {
     return ;
    }
    $entries = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('modulesettings/catalogprint/displayattributes', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    $entries = explode(',', $entries);
    $displayattributes = $this->displayattributes->getOriginalOption();
    $result = array();
    foreach($displayattributes as $key => $value) 
    {
        if(in_array($key, $entries)) 
        {
        $result[] = $value;
        }
    }
        return $result;
}

public function getallattributes()
{
    $arr = [];
    $attributeInfo = $this->_attributeFactory->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set::KEY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID, 4);

   foreach($attributeInfo as $attributes)
   {
        $attributeId = $attributes->getAttributeId();
        // You can get all fields of attribute here

         $arr[$attributes->getAttributeId()] = $attributes->getFrontendLabel();


   }
   return $arr;

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
    public function getallattributes()
    {
        $arr = [];
        $attributeInfo = $this->_attributeFactory->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set::KEY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID, 4);

        foreach($attributeInfo as $attributes)
        {
             $attributeId = $attributes->getAttributeId();
             // You can get all fields of attribute here
             if($attributes->getIsVisibleOnFront()){
                  $arr[$attributes->getAttributeId()] = $attributes->getFrontendLabel();
             }


        }
        return $arr;

     }
```